# Spring JSF 2 View Scope $Proxy115 no property

Tags: spring, jsf, scope, view-scope

I'm creating an app using Spring 3 and JSF 2. I used custom ViewScope implementation from https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/primefaces-spring-scopes. I registered custom scope.

The problem is that when I try to access page where view scoped bean is used I get following exception:

```
INFO - ViewScope - Creating bean {editUser}
INFO - EditUser - EditUser() - class[com.myapp.beans.EditUser@f0ac4], rewId[null]
INFO - ViewScope - registerDestructionCallback for bean editUser
INFO - ViewScope - Session event bound sessionBindingListener
INFO - ViewScope - Bean created {com.myapp.beans.EditUser@f0ac4}
2013-03-18 00:30:30 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase execute
WARNING: /editUser.xhtml @10,78 value="#{editUser.rewId}": The class '$Proxy115' does not have the property 'rewId'.
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /editUser.xhtml @10,78 value="#{editUser.rewId}": The class '$Proxy115' does not have the property 'rewId'.
```

When bean is session scoped everything works fine.

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem caused by JDK-based proxies generated to deal with `@Transactional` annotation.

JDK proxies are created only for *interfaces* implemented by the class (in your case `Serializable)`. So, you proxy have only methods from `Serializable` interfaces (not at all).

To fix the problem you need to switch to another proxy mode (using cglib), for example using:
`@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)`. Also, add `cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2` to dependencies of the project.

Comment: I've got it set, and accessor methods are there, must be something else, another bean which is simplier works fine as view scoped

Comment: Looks like it because some proxy crated over bean. Could you provide EditUser code?

Comment: ping-ping? (btw, I am author of code you using for ViewScope, so want to find fix too)

Comment: the class is very complicated so it's hard to paste it here, however I marked all properties as transient and the error still occurs, maybe there is a problem with some methods inside it or the types they return (but this seems to be ridiculous)

Comment: I don't know how transient fields may change anything to be honest.. Anyway Proxy115 is name of proxy class created by Spring for some reason (maybe it is annotated by @Transactional or something about it...). And I think it is possible source of the problem. Please provide next things:

Your class declaration (including annotations),
rewId getter and setter code,
xhtml header (with imports),
xhtml code you use to access rewId.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Transient fields are not serialized and ViewScope requires bean to be serializable, using this my class seems to be very simple for serialization.

Comment: I have methods annotated with @Transactional (that's normal I  think). Class is annotated only as follow:  
    &amp;Named("editUserBean")   
    &amp;SpringViewScoped   
    public class EditUserBean implements Serializable {   
   
Getter/setter for rewId are very simple, generated by IDE.

Comment: looks like the Proxy exception arises when I'm adding "implements Serializable" to the bean

Comment: O, I think I know the problem. It is because way your proxy-weaving implemented - if there is any interface implemented - Spring generates JDK-based proxy for it (check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460599/java-jsf-tomcat-spring-proxy-object-has-different-methods-than-original-object)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found that the Transactional annotation was problematic, after removing it and managing transaction manually everything works fine

Comment: unfortunately @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true) is not working and I still get the same error when @Transactional is used, I'm maintaining transactions manually and it works fine, maybe somebody will find a better solution, I have no time for this now

Answer (score 0):

This is a ViewScope problem, it creates dummy versions, read over here: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24082